# alfresco custom action for secure timestamp - error using BouncyCastle

Tags: java, maven, alfresco, bouncycastle

I'm a newbie to developing to alfresco so here is my question. I'm developing a custom action in alfresco wich goal is to create a detached Secure Time Stamp of a document.
Here's my code:

```
    String tsaUrl = "http://ts.cartaodecidadao.pt/tsa/server";
    OutputStream out = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    MessageDigest hash;
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
        hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        try{
           is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
           final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
           for (int i = 0; is.read(buffer) != -1;){
                hash.update(buffer, 0, i);
           }
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                
            TimeStampRequestGenerator timeStampRequestGenerator = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();

            /*FIXME */
            ASN1ObjectIdentifier algorithm = TSPAlgorithms.SHA1;
            TimeStampRequest timeStampRequest = timeStampRequestGenerator.generate(algorithm, hash.digest());
            byte request[] = timeStampRequest.getEncoded();

            URL url = new URL(tsaUrl);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-type",
                    "application/timestamp-query");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-length",
                    String.valueOf(request.length));
            out = con.getOutputStream();
            out.write(request);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            if (con.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                System.out.println("---------- != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK");
                throw new IOException("Received HTTP error: "
                        + con.getResponseCode() + " - "
                        + con.getResponseMessage());
            }

            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            TimeStampResp resp = TimeStampResp
                    .getInstance(new ASN1InputStream(in).readObject());
            TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(resp);
```

It builds successfully but when trying the action, it throws an error the line after where is the comment "FIXME". The stack-trace of the error is

```
2015-07-09 00:58:32,598  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-bio-8080-exec-8] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 06090002 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06090015 The action failed to execute due to an error.
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 06090002 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 06090015 The action failed to execute due to an error.
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:470)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:454)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:532)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:600)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:380)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:261)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.action.ActionServiceException: 06090015 The action failed to execute due to an error.
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:816)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:573)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.executeAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.rule.ActionQueuePost.executeImpl(ActionQueuePost.java:85)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:64)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bouncycastle.tsp.TSPAlgorithms
    at pt.ubi.release.SecureTimeStamp_repo.action.StampAction.executeImpl(StampAction.java:233)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:265)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:839)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:739)
```

Did anyone knows why it says it could not initializa class org.bouncycastle.tsp.TSPAlgorithms? Btw, i'm using version 1.52 of bouncycastle libraries.
Sorry about my english but it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

**NoClassDefFoundError** indicates that the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the .class file for the class that you're trying to use.  So, probably jar is not added to class path for class **org.bouncycastle.tsp.TSPAlgorithms**

You probably need to add that bouncycastle jar in alfresco/Web-INF/lib if you are trying to run this action within Alfresco.

Comment: yes, I know that, I already add the dependecies to pom,xml and when I build the project and deploy it, it added the libraries automatically